# Help with the KKT conditions of a SPT problem

Tags: vehicle-routing, kkt-conditions, continuous-optimization

Could anyone help me with the KKT conditions of my problem? The different sums and sets confuse me more than a little.

$$
\min_x \sum_{a \in A^1} p_a^1 X_a + \sum_{a \in A^2} p_a^2 X_a + \sum_{a \in A^3} p_a^3 X_a \\
\text{s.t.} \sum_{a \in A: \text{Tail}(a) = i} X_a - \sum_{a \in A: \text{Head}(a) = i} X_a = \begin{cases} \;1, \;\; i = s \\ -1, \; i = t \\ \;0, \;\; \forall i \in N - \{s,t\} \end{cases} \\ 
\sum_{a \in A^2} X_a + \sum_{a \in A^3} X_a = 1 \\
X_a \geq 0 \;\;\;\forall a \in A
$$

$N$ is the set of nodes, and $A$ is the set of edges. Furthermore, $A=A^1 \cup A^2 \cup A^3 \cup A^4$.

I have trouble deriving the stationary conditions.

Edit:
Here is what I did.

[image]

Comment: Can you include your steps apply KKT and where you got stuck?

Comment: I just add a picture of how I think it should be.